# Django ORM, Exclude on two values

Tags: django, orm

I want to gain and OR operation in my exclude statement.

Like:

```
Select all those records where name is NOT Mason and Status is NOT Unactive
```

### OR

```
Select all those records where name is NOT Mason and Status is active
```

### Tried.

```
Users.objects.exclude(name="Mason", active=False)
```

But this is not an `OR` operation but `AND`. How to get `OR` operation.

Comment: Actually you have to use exclude twice to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) doc. For your case:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q1 = Q(name="Mason")
q2 = Q(active=False)

Users.objects.exclude( q1 | q2 )
```

Or, more closed tou your SQL

```
#where name is NOT Mason and Status is NOT Unactive
Users.objects.filter( ~q1 & ~q2 )

#where name is NOT Mason and Status is active
q2 = Q(active=True)
Users.objects.filter( ~q1 & q2 )
```

Comment: Worked without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use exclude with OR opration. you have to use exclude twice.

```
Entry.objects.exclude(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 3)).exclude(headline='Hello')
```

### OR

```
User.objects.exclude(name="Mason").exclude(active=False)
```

### Reference

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)